# Swift Beacon doesn't work now using Swift 3.0

Tags: swift, swift3, ibeacon, beacon

I have been following a guide to using Swift to create a Beacon proximity app, but since updating Xcode and updating the code to Swift 3.0 I am getting a fatal error.

Going through the functions I think there is an issue with the startScanning function, when it fires I get fatal error message.

Any hints at to what could help would be greatly appreciated:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var distanceLabel: UILabel!
var locationManager: CLLocationManager!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    print("did load")

}


func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    if status == CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedAlways{
        print("status authorized")
        if CLLocationManager.isMonitoringAvailable(for: CLBeaconRegion.self){
            print("is monitoring")
            if CLLocationManager.isRangingAvailable() {
                print("scanning")
                startScanning()

            }
        }
    }
}




func startScanning() {
    print("start Scanning")
    let uuid = NSUUID(uuidString: "695e5f08824c785cadc72e1dde23be04")
    let beaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: uuid as! UUID, identifier: "MyBeacon")

    locationManager.startMonitoring(for: beaconRegion)
    locationManager.startRangingBeacons(in: beaconRegion)
}



func updateDistance(distance: CLProximity){

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) { [unowned self] in

        switch distance {
        case .unknown:
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
            self.distanceLabel.text = "UNKNOWN"
            print("distance Unknown")
        case .far:
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
            self.distanceLabel.text = "FAR"
            print("distance Far")
        case .near:
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
            self.distanceLabel.text = "NEAR"
            print("distance Near")
        case .immediate:
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            self.distanceLabel.text = "BOOM!"
            print("distance Immediate")
        }
    }
}



func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion) {
    if beacons.count > 0 {
        let beacon = beacons.first! as CLBeacon
        updateDistance(distance: beacon.proximity)
        print("found more than one beacon")
    } else {
        updateDistance(distance: .unknown)
        print("found only one beacon")
    }
}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
2016-09-27 17:27:35.045701 Prject 22[3211:825691] fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your UUID is in the wrong format, so this line fails to parse it, assigning nil to the variable `uuid`:

```
let uuid = NSUUID(uuidString: "695e5f08824c785cadc72e1dde23be04")
```

The program will then crash using the `uuid as! UUID` operation because ! will crash if there is a nil value.

To fix this, you need to add dashes at the appropriate places in the UUID string.  You should also avoid using the ! operator to force unwrap optional variables in Swift, as it can cause crashes like this.  Try this:

```
if let uuid = NSUUID(uuidString: "695e5f08-824c-785c-adc7-2e1dde23be04") {
  let beaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: uuid, identifier: "MyBeacon")
  locationManager.startMonitoring(for: beaconRegion)
  locationManager.startRangingBeacons(in: beaconRegion)
}
else {
  NSLog("Invalid UUID format")
}
```

When running check that the code does not go down the "Invalid UUID format" path.

Comment: Thank you! This has solved the startScanning fund issue, but now there is a problem with the locationManager fund, but I will see what I can do myself. Thanks again